# Performance tuning for SCALA-Ide plugin on Eclipse 2020-03

Tags: eclipse, scala-ide

I'm learning Apache spark with scala and using scala-ide for eclipse on my desktop. Seems like there is a need of performance optimizations for my eclipse-ide since it keeps going into non-responsive state on quite often (and recovers in 2-3 secs). Any suggestions?

My eclipse.ini looks like this -

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.700.v20200207-2156.jar
--launcher.library
C:\Users\<username>\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.1100.v20190907-0426
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-showsplash
C:\Users\<username>\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.epp.package.common_4.15.0.20200313-1200
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_241/bin/javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
-XX:PermSize=512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Xmx2048m
-Xms1024m
```

Comment: That is probably caused by a plugin you have installed. Which plugin causes UI freezes can be found by using _UI Responsiveness Monitoring_ (which can be enabled in _Window > Preferences: General > UI Responsiveness Monitoring_). Therefore. tuning the Eclipse platform (e.g. by using a newer Java VM to run Eclipse) would probably have almost no effect.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply! I'll try this out.